# Trying to get Tidyverse installed in Linux mint 20.2

Tags: r, linux, tidyverse

I've been working on getting RStudio to open on and off for the last few days, finally got it running and started installing packages. Readr installed fine but tidyverse refuses to install.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(v3_genn.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `GENERAL_NAME_it' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: openssl.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/william/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘ids’
* removing ‘/home/william/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/ids’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ids’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/william/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘gargle’
* removing ‘/home/william/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/gargle’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gargle’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘rvest’
* removing ‘/home/william/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rvest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘gargle’, ‘httr’ are not available for package ‘googledrive’
* removing ‘/home/william/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/googledrive’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googledrive’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘gargle’, ‘googledrive’, ‘httr’, ‘ids’ are not available for package ‘googlesheets4’
* removing ‘/home/william/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/googlesheets4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googlesheets4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘googledrive’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘httr’, ‘rvest’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/william/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpyoCTNu/downloaded_packages’
```

To fix this I've tried suggestions from two places:

The first option was 'sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev'

from this website: https://blog.zenggyu.com/en/post/2018-01-29/installing-r-r-packages-e-g-tidyverse-and-rstudio-on-ubuntu-linux/

The second this was 'sudo apt-get install r-base-dev xml2 libxml2-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev unixodbc-dev'

from the rstudio community page: https://community.rstudio.com/t/cant-install-tidyverse/29293

A third option I found that is too advanced for me without guidance is this:
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH and
PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. I think something may not be in the proper place or is linked to the wrong location. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

(Also,for reference, this is the first time I've used linux so please dumb answers down as much as possible)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Might be an issue with libssl-dev; do you get any errors if you type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you need from the output so I'll try to break it up and put everything

Comment: Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Ign:2 http://packages.linuxmint.com uma InRelease                              
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:4 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ InRelease     
Hit:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com uma Release                                
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:7 http://dell.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease

Comment: Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                 
Hit:9 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                           
Hit:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [27.6 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [61.0 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]

Comment: Fetched 205 kB in 2s (128 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libhal1-flash
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
Suggested packages:
  libssl-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,584 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,008 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Comment: Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssl-dev amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8 [1,584 kB]
Fetched 1,584 kB in 1s (1,460 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package libssl-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 423030 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl-dev_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8) ...
Setting up libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.8) ...

And then it stopped there

Answer (score 4):

I've now gotten this to work. By looking at the error messages I found the dependencies that need to be installed before tidyverse can be installed (and function).

It is preferable but not necessary to get the latest version of R installed. I followed the steps in this tutorial:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-rstudio-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

In the interest of putting everything in one place, I'll put the steps here:

Step 1:

`$ sudo apt update`

`$ sudo apt -y install r-base gdebi-core`

Step 2: Install Rstudio from their website

Step 3: For this step, make sure you're in the folder that has the file downloaded, for me that was in downloads

`$ sudo gdebi rstudio-1.2.5019-amd64.deb`

Step 4: Open Rstudio

To get tidyverse to work, my error messages were all about non-zero exit statuses. What I did was to go through, find the packages that weren't properly installing, and manually install them.

My first problem was with curl. I tried installing it in Rstudio first. When I got an error, I went into terminal and installed it with

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

If openssl refuses to install try:

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

I tried installing tidyverse again, no dice. It was still having trouble with xml2 and rvest. I installed xml2 in terminal with.

`sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`

After that, rvest installed using Rstudio and tidyverse installed successfully.

These instructions work with both R 4.1.1 and R 3.4.4

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the R version here is quite old, version 3.6.  A bunch of things that are tidyverse related broke around the switch from 3.* to 4.*.

If you follow a procedure like this, it should get you started on the right path with the proper R version and the rest will likely fall into place.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Occasionally, on linux machines, you will have packages that fail to install because of system level dependencies that are missing.  Those messages are usually informative; they will tell you what you need and the command for acquiring it.

Comment: so I've now tried that and while following those directions on linux mint 20.2 it installed version 3.6.3. Is there a way to force it to install 4.0.1? Also, I've switched computers, as the old one wouldn't recognize the touchpad. I'm now on the Dell Inspiron 15

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-rstudio-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

by following the directions on here, I've now gotten to R 4.1.1, will update if tidyverse works

Comment: Failure again. the errors seem to all relate to google things:

* DONE (modelr)
ERROR: dependencies ‘googledrive’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘httr’, ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/william/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/Rtmpy9RMqS/downloaded_packages’

any suggestions on what to try next? would it just be the 'apt install' function?