# Installing packages has non-zero status; dependencies unavailable - version problem?

Tags: r, linux

I am using Rstudio 2023.03.0 and R base 2023.03.0 on Linux mint 20.3.
Installing various packages doesn't seem to work because either dependencies or other packages are unmet. However, installing dependencies doesn't seem possible as they are not available.

Installing various packages in rstudio seems very hard or impossible. Installing tidyverse required various packages from the terminal (not dependencies), but I managed to manually install what it needed, so that

> install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies = TRUE)

Does not return 'non-zeto exit status' any longer (although parts of the package still seem not to be installed).

When I try to install rstatix, though, I get an error with a list of unmet dependencies:
emmeans
pbkrtest
car
ggpubr

After trying to manually install those in turn (including dependencies = TRUE) in RStudio, I get a simple error:

> package ‘emmeans’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

This is the case for the other dependencies as well. I checked the Package Managment in Tools, only to find a 'CRAN repositories modified outside package preferences' error

I don't know what to do about that. Hope this makes sense, and that I gave some useful context, however I'm out of my depth a bit here.

EDIT:
So an obivous thing which I neglected to check is that my R base is outdated. This brought up an older issue, I could not update R base via cran's instructions:

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.3-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However, if I try to install r-recommended, I get into a recursion of unmet dependencies until I hit a wall where a dependency is missing.

Comment: Your last error means what it says: the package is not available for that version of R (3.6.3) - emmeans depends on R 4.1.0 or higher. So you need to update your R version.

Comment: *"R version 3.6.3"*? Time to update R? You can find the packages missing in the [CRAN archives](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/).

Comment: Maybe have a look at: [How to install Tidyverse on Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719942)

Comment: Or: [Trying to get Tidyverse installed in Linux mint 20.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992346)

Comment: Or: tidyverse as CRAN binaires in eighteen seconds ([demo](https://twitter.com/eddelbuettel/status/1614801943951458304)) if you use [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/).  For Linux, it is difficult to get _consistent_ and _complete_ binary repositories for CRAN but [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) is one. The c2d4u PPA is a partial alternative which covers about a third of CRAN, older SO answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57514683/revisions).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 1):

Update R or install an older version of the package that does not requires a newer R.